# Deploying and configuring Postgres server in Azure with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm deploying Azure Postgres Flexible Server with Terraform as described in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/terraform/tree/master/quickstart/201-postgresql-fs-db). The configuration works as expected, no issues there. The only divination from that GitHub template is that I want to configure pgBouncer for Postgres which is now supported natively. I don't see a way how I can create this configuration (i.e., enable this feature).

I've done some research and discovered the configuration feature is not quite available (at least according to the open ticket in GitHub [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13479)). At the same time, one of the published replies suggests using `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration` and this resource type is available in Terraform indeed. However, [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-pgbouncer) states that to enable and configure pgBouncer I need to introduce 7 parameters. I thought that to make the code tidier, I can use a list and foreach loop, like this:

```
locals {
  pg_config = {
    "pgbouncer.default_pool_size" : "50",
    "pgBouncer.max_client_conn"   : "5000",
    "pgBouncer.pool_mode"         : "TRANSACTION"
    etc...
  }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "postgres_fs_config" {
  for_each = local.pg_config
  name = each.key
  value = each.value
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgres-fs.id
}
```

Is this the best way to configure Postgres (without involving CDK)? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I verified this approach and it works like a charm. Will stick to it for now.